# Adding to list duplicate item

Tags: c#

if I add an item with certain date and name when I add another item with the same date and name, the first item information expect the date and the name changed to the last one information.
But if I save the list to the database and call the list again and add an item with the same name and date it works. The list contains objects of the following

```
   public class Food
   {
     public  string date = "";
     public string name = "";
     public float amount = 0;
     public short meal = 0;
   }
```

it goes like this:

```
List<Food> foods = new List<Food>();
//the first
Food object1=new Food();
object1.date = "20211010";
object1.name = "Orange";
object1.amount = 10;
object1.meal = 2; 
   
foods.Add(object1);

//the second   
var object2=new Food();
object2.date = "20211010";
object2.name = "Orange";
object2.amount = 50;
object2.meal = 3; 

 foods.Add(object2);

 string xx="";
 foreach(Food fd in foods)
 {
     xx +=fd.date+"  "+fd.name+"   "+fd.amount+"    "+fd.meal+"\n";
 }

 MessageBox.Show(xx);
           
       The result shown :
         20211010   Orange 50 3
         20211010   Orange 50 3
```

If I add another item with another name it works fine.
if I after entering the first item and save the list and then recall the list and add the second item it works fine also.
But it works like above if more than one item with the same name is added to the list in the save process.

How to solve that?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is this the _actual_ code?

Comment: Let's start to say that after fixing all the errors in the code shown, the result is not the one you have shown, but the correct one with two different Food objects

Comment: What does MessageBox do?

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane one of the many errors. It is MessageBox.Show

Comment: Works as expected here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O8pzRK